# Is there a way to execute ARM template which is under Templates in Azure via PowerShell/CLI

Tags: powershell, azure-resource-manager

I have created a ARM and saved under templates in my account in Azure portal.
Now I am planning to run the saved arm templates via Powershell/CLI.

if the ARM templates are saved in my local m/c then I can easily upload them and run from powershell. but my questions is how to run templates which are saved in portal under Templates using powershell command

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have did a repro in our local environment ,You cannot deploy those saved ARM templates using Azure CLI or PowerShell.

- you can convert those [Saved templates to ARM template spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-spec-convert)   as discussed in this documentation.

if those templates were saved as template spec you can deploy those arm templates using either PowerShell or Azure CLI

- [Power shell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell#deploy-template-spec) to deploy arm template spec :

```html
 $id = (Get-AzTemplateSpec -Name storageSpec -ResourceGroupName templateSpecsRg -Version 1.0).Version.Id
    
    New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
      -ResourceGroupName demoRG `
      -TemplateSpecId $id
```

- [AzureCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli#deploy-template-spec) commands to deploy arm template spec:

```html
id = $(az ts show --name storageSpec --resource-group templateSpecRG --version "1.0" --query "id")
        
        az deployment group create \
          --resource-group demoRG \
          --template-spec $id
```

Here is the reference ,For information about [ARM template spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-specs?tabs=azure-powershell)